# Unresolved External Symbols in DLL using lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, dll

I have the following structure part of a DLL:

Utils.h

```
#ifdef _EXPORTS
#    define UTILS_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#    define UTILS_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

namespace Utils
{
    static auto MyCustomComparator = [](std::shared_ptr<IMyType>& o1, std::shared_ptr<IMyType>& o2) {
        // do some stuff and compare o1 and o2
    };

    using MyCustomPriorityQueue = std::priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<IMyType>, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<IMyType>>, decltype(MyCustomComparator)>;

    UTILS_API void Foo(MyCustomPriorityQueue& myQueue);
}
```

Utils.cpp

```
#include "Utils.h"

namespace Utils
{
    UTILS_API void Foo(MyCustomPriorityQueue & myQueue)
    {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

These get built into a DLL that is then linked into an executable that creates a `MyCustomPriorityQueue` and calls `Foo`.

Tool.cpp

```
#include "Utils.h"

int main()
{
    MyCustomPriorityQueue myQueue(MyCustomComparator);

    // add things to queue
    myQueue.emplace(...)

    Utils::Foo(myQueue);
}
```

This fails to build with `unresolved externals` on the `Foo` API. Any ideas on what could cause this? I know that until I added the priority queue with the custom comparator as part of the exported API (it used to be internal to `Foo`), it all worked, so something is definitely going wrong during linking and figuring out the type of the custom priority queue maybe?

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl Utils::Foo(struct class std::priority_queue<class std::shared_ptr<class Utils::IMyType>,class std::vector<class std::shared_ptr<class Utils::IMyType>,class std::allocator<class std::shared_ptr<class Utils::IMyType> > >,class <lambda_19161500ece6d0a8a5b52705767e713b> const > &)" (__imp_?Foo@Utils@@$priority_queue@V?$shared_ptr@VIMyType@Utils@@@std@@V?$vector@V?$shared_ptr@VIMyType@Utils@@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$shared_ptr@VIMyType@Utils@@@std@@@2@@2@$$CBV<lambda_19161500ece6d0a8a5b52705767e713b>@@@std@@@Z)
bin\Tool.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to ensure this:
By creating DLL the macro _EXPORTS **should be** defined.
In the client code using DLL the macro _EXPORTS **should not** be defined.

Also note regarding **lambda**: the 2 compilation units including the same header file, will see the different lambda types, because every lambda has different type. For example, in this sample code:

```
auto a = []() {};
auto b = []() {};
```

the types a and b would be different.

I dont think you can use lambda in your case. Just declare regular type.

Depending on what platform you compile, you could use **dumpbin** (if win) or **readelf** (if unix) to check the exported symbols of your dll and importing symbols for the client.

Comment: Yes, I am ensuring that part. For example, if I change my definition of `MyCustomPriorityQueue` from:

`using MyCustomPriorityQueue = std::priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<IMyType>, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<IMyType>>, decltype(MyCustomComparator)>;`

to

`using MyCustomPriorityQueue = std::priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<IMyType>>;`

building everything is fine. There is definitely something wrong with the type of the lambda...

Comment: I am going to look into dumpbin and see what is going on. Thanks for that suggestion!

Comment: With dumpbin, I get what I kinda expected, which is also what the linker errors about.

Comment: I have edited my answer: in the principle the dll code and client code including same header file will see different lambda types.

Comment: I see, I suspect that is the issue - is there a way to aggregate that definition of the lambda such that both see it the same? Or should I create the custom comparator in a different way?

Comment: I dont think you can use lambda in your case. Just declare regular type.

Comment: I ended up just using the regular class and `operator()` overload and that worked. Thanks a lot for the help! I assume this was all due to the fact that lambdas are anonymous types are they are _different_ anonymous types in each compilation unit, as you suggested.

Will also give inline static a try for the sake of seeing if I can get it to work with lambdas eventually

Comment: Yes, `inline static` did not work either. Regular overload it is then. Thanks again! This was good for learning too :)